# how can i set my project according to firefox?

Tags: java, firefox, jsp, browser

My project  works troubleless in internet explorer but in firefox or other browsers it faces problems which  for example it does not show my captcha characthers in the right style. my project is writen in java , jsp . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser specific issues *ususally* does not have anything to do with JSP or Java part of the code. it is more likely that you need to look into (1)*CSS* included on the page, (2) *JavaScript* that's getting executed.

Test on Firefox using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension to resolve what's wrong with FireFox.

See this article on *QuirksMode* [CSS contents and browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Comment: Or, crappy non-standard *HTML* (easily the broken'est thing i've found when stuff shows up all wacky).