# the navigation of my project does not work in the right way in mozilla how can i solve this problem?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i set my project according to firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151965/how-can-i-set-my-project-according-to-firefox)

My project works in internet explorer but in other browsers it does not work in the right style I tried firebug but I dont how I solve this problem or how can i create a menu which can work in all browsers.

Comment: if you can put some code or a link to live example to see what is the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i set my project according to firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151965/how-can-i-set-my-project-according-to-firefox) @user, please start improving your questions **massively** by providing more context and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is most likely that you used non-standard or IE-specific HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Since you haven't posted any specifics the only thing I can suggest is starting off validating your HTML and CSS and correcting **all** errors.

http://validator.w3.org/

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: thanks, for your answer. Also when I remove  (position: absolute;) from my project All menus seems correctly but in this time project does not work correctly. how does it affect my project

Comment: You really, really, really need to create questions with more relevant information (for example sample code or URL) rather than just re-asking the same thing again or asking in comments. You'll get better and more answers if you put more effort in it.